# Is this a verilog race condition?

Tags: verilog

Is there something about this code that would produce a race condition? If I run it as is, seems to hang. If I make the small change noted below it performs as intended.

This isn't the complete code, I just wanted to post enough to see if someone recognized something obvious. I'm stumped. I can post the entire code is someone wants it. Thanks.

```
wire clk;        

// core
reg src_in; // 0 = ram, 1 = uart
initial src_in = 1'b1; 
reg src_out;
initial src_out = 1'b1;
reg src_in_;
reg src_out_;
wire [7:0] I = src_in ? term_in : data_read;
wire emit;

always @* begin         

    // //src_in
    case(I)
        "}" :       src_in_ = 1'b1; // 1 = uart 
        "]" :       src_in_ = 1'b0; // 0 = ram
        default:    src_in_ = src_in; //!!!!!!!!!! if I change this to 1'b0 there is no problem
    endcase         


    // //src_out
    case(I)
        "{" :       src_out_ = 1'b1; // 1 = uart 
        "[" :       src_out_ = 1'b0; // 0 = ram
        default:    src_out_ = src_out; //!!!!!!!!!! if I change this to 1'b0 there is no problem
    endcase     

end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    {R, L} <= {R_, L_};
    {src_in, src_out} <= {src_in_, src_out_};
end
```

Comment: does not look like this is all the code. There is not much in it which could cause hanging. I can speculate that a zero-delay loop is coming from 'scr_in ->scr_in_ -> ... scr_out  ->...-> I` chain. But there is not enough code to see it.  Check spelling of the var names. Underscores could easily be missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code 'hangs' you have a combinatorial loop, not a race condition.
Thus somewhere you have a series of `a=b; b=c; c=~d; d=a;`

I don't immediately see one in the code above so I suspect it is in the code you do not show.

One way of finding those is to step through the code.

That can be very tedious with a big design so another way you can try is to sprinkle delays throughout the code where you suspect the problem is (e.g. add `#5;`) and check the waveform, **That is for debugging only!!**
In that case make sure your clock is much slower. e.g. use #1000.

This is an example waveform I made of a combinatorial loop (`a=~b&clk; b=a;`)with a #5 in it:

[image]